# How can I process the LISP style tree generated by Antlr 4?

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr4, parse-tree, s-expression

I parsed an SQL query using an Antlr 4 grammar.
The result of tree.toStringTree() is this:
([] ([845] SELECT ([878 845] ([1473 878 845] ([1129 1473 878 845] ([1700 1129 1473 878 845] col1))) as ([1477 878 845] a)) FROM ([887 845] ([1487 887 845] ([1694 1487 887 845] table1)))))

Antlr documentation tells me this  is a LISP style tree. How can I further process a LISP tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's friendlier for your eyes if you provide the `Parser` instance:

```
SQLiteLexer lexer = new SQLiteLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(sql));
SQLiteParser parser = new SQLiteParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree tree = parser.select_stmt();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

As to your question of processing this string: you shouldn't. It is just for displaying the tree. Just as a normal `toString()` works. You should not parse this string because there is no guarantee it will look the same from version to version.

I've suggested it before, but will do so again: if you want to get a hierarchical structure, just work with `ParseTree`, it has parent and child references. If that is not what you want, please explain yourself better.

Comment: Hi @Bart - Thanks for the insights. An extremely basic question, do the numbers in the Tree String represent token numbers assigned by the Lexer?

Comment: @user3898179, no problem. If by "number" you mean the `int` that denotes the token-type, then yes, that is assigned by the lexer.